# Magento 2 - Override base view file

Tags: magento2

I'm currently developing a Magento 2.0 theme. I'm trying to change the behaviour of the Tax class on the frontend. The file I need to change is located in app/Code/Magento/Tax/view/**base**/templates/pricing/adjustment.phtml.

How can I override this view from my Magento theme?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Copy adjustment.phtml file from base template and put it in `app/design/frontend/[VendorName]/[theme]/Magento_Tax/pricing/adjustment.phtml`

For more information you can get help from : http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/themes/theme-inherit.html

Answer (score 1):

The solution was simple, just create the file in app/design/frontend/[VendorName]/[theme]/Magento_Tax/templates/pricing/adjustment.phtml.

Explanation (and credits): https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/84550/magento-2-override-base-view-file

Answer (score 0):

```
app/design/frontend/[VendorName]/[theme]/Magento_Tax/templates/pricing/adjustment.phtml.
```

Then after don't forget to run this bellow command.

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```